# ASP PostBack not posting all controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP page that contains a DDL tied to a select query and gridview. After `pageLoad` I can select a value and populate the gridview with no issues.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
 <asp:ListItem>Select an entry</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem>Requested</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem>Requested and Closed</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem>Ordered</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem>Working</asp:ListItem> 
 <asp:ListItem>Warranty Parts</asp:ListItem> 
 <asp:ListItem>Warranty Service</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem>Filled</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

protected void DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //string choice = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text;
    int index = DropDownList3.SelectedIndex;
    string query;
    switch (index)
    {
        case 0:
            {
                query = "SELECT TOP 100 [last_name], [zpart_used_manual], [zpart_used_SN], [serial_number], [ref_num], [status], [summary], [id], [zpart_used_completed] FROM [VIEW_USS_ICG_Parts_Requested] ORDER BY [last_name]";
                break;
            }
        case 1:
            {
                query = "SELECT TOP 100 [last_name], [zpart_used_manual], [zpart_used_SN], [serial_number], [ref_num], [status], [summary], [id], [zpart_used_completed] FROM [VIEW_USS_ICG_Parts_Requested] WHERE [status]='WAIT-PR' ORDER BY [last_name]";
                break;
            }
        case 2:
            {
                query = "SELECT [last_name], [zpart_used_manual], [zpart_used_SN], [serial_number], [ref_num], [status], [summary], [id], [zpart_used_completed] FROM [VIEW_USS_ICG_Parts_Requested] WHERE ([zpart_used_completed] IS NULL) AND ([status]='WAIT-PR' OR [status]='CLO')  ORDER BY [last_name]";
                break;
            }
        case 3:
            {
                query = "SELECT TOP 100 [last_name], [zpart_used_manual], [zpart_used_SN], [serial_number], [ref_num], [status], [summary], [id], [zpart_used_completed] FROM [VIEW_USS_ICG_Parts_Requested] WHERE [status]='WAIT-PO' ORDER BY [last_name]";
                break;
            }
        case 4:
            {
                query = "SELECT TOP 100 [last_name], [zpart_used_manual], [zpart_used_SN], [serial_number], [ref_num], [status], [summary], [id], [zpart_used_completed] FROM [VIEW_USS_ICG_Parts_Requested] WHERE [status]='WORK' ORDER BY [last_name]";
                break;
            }
        case 5:
            {
                query = "SELECT TOP 100 [last_name], [zpart_used_manual], [zpart_used_SN], [serial_number], [ref_num], [status], [summary], [id], [zpart_used_completed] FROM [VIEW_USS_ICG_Parts_Requested] WHERE [status]='WAIT - WP' OR [status]='WAIT-W' ORDER BY [last_name]";
                break;
            }
        case 6:
            {
                query = "SELECT [last_name], [zpart_used_manual], [zpart_used_SN], [serial_number] , [ref_num], [status], [summary], [id], (SELECT [DDvalue] FROM zpartStatuses WHERE [code] = [zpart_used_completed] ) AS [zpart_used_completed] FROM View_USS_ICG_Parts_Requested INNER JOIN zpartStatuses ON [zpart_used_completed] = zpartStatuses.code WHERE ([status] = 'WAIT - WS')ORDER BY [last_name]";
                break;
            }
        case 7:
            {
                query = "SELECT [last_name], [zpart_used_manual], [zpart_used_SN], [serial_number], [ref_num], [status], [summary], [id], [zpart_used_completed] FROM [VIEW_USS_ICG_Parts_Requested] WHERE [zpart_used_completed] = '1' ORDER BY [last_name]";
                //query = "SELECT TOP 100 [last_name], [zpart_used_manual], [zpart_used_SN], [serial_number], [ref_num], [status], [summary], [id], [zpart_used_completed] FROM [VIEW_USS_ICG_Parts_Requested] ORDER BY [last_name]";
                break;
            }
        default:
            {
                query = "SELECT TOP 100 [last_name], [zpart_used_manual], [zpart_used_SN], [serial_number], [ref_num], [status], [summary], [id], [zpart_used_completed] FROM [VIEW_USS_ICG_Parts_Requested] ORDER BY [last_name]";
                break;
            }

    }
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;Initial Catalog=mdb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pass");
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
    sqlConnection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataSource = reader;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

Inside the gridview I have an item template containing another DDL which triggers an update query on that row.

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
 DataTextField="DDvalue" DataValueField="code" Height="20px" Width="150px" 
 AutoPostBack="True" CommandName="DD4" OnSelectedIndexChanged = "DDL4_SelectedIndexChanged">
 </asp:DropDownList>        

protected void DDL4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sqlQueryString2 = "UPDATE [act_log] SET [zpart_used_completed]= @status, [zpart_used_status] = @date  WHERE [id] = @id";
    SqlConnection sqlConnectionCmdString2 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;Initial Catalog=mdb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pass");
    int status;
    GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)((DataControlFieldCell)((DropDownList)sender).Parent).Parent;
    DropDownList d4 = (DropDownList)gr.FindControl("DropDownList4");
    status = d4.SelectedIndex;
    string id = GridView1.Rows[gr.RowIndex].Cells[10].Text;             
    sqlConnectionCmdString2.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlQueryCmd2 = new SqlCommand(sqlQueryString2, sqlConnectionCmdString2);
    sqlQueryCmd2.Parameters.Add("@id", id);
    sqlQueryCmd2.Parameters.Add("@status", status);
    sqlQueryCmd2.Parameters.Add("@date", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
    sqlQueryCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlQueryCmd2.Dispose();
    sqlConnectionCmdString2.Close();
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

Both DDLs are set up for AutoPostBack. The issue is that when the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event is tripped from `DropDownList4` it does not bring the page back to the results of `DropDownList3`. What the page is instead pulling is:

```
 <EmptyDataTemplate>
 No records could be retrieved from the database.  We apologize for the invonvenience.
 </EmptyDataTemplate>
```

How can I get the page to refresh the gridview on each modification?

Comment: post the code behind in the .cs file to see whats going on

Answer (score 0):

The `AutoPostBack` property causes a postback (obviously). Remove `this.Databind();` from your `!IsPostBack`.

```
if (!IsPostBack) {
    this.DataBind();
}
```

becomes:

```
this.DataBind();
```

**Update:**

Do you have ViewState enabled on the GridView?

**Update:**

Okay, I think see the problem now. In the handler for `DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged`, you set `DataSource` for `GridView1`:

```
GridView1.DataSource = reader;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

and then, in the `DDL4_SelectedIndexChanged` postback handler, you attempt to rebind `GridView1` without specifying another datasource.

```
GridView1.DataBind();
```

If `GridView1` had its `DataSource` set declaratively (in the ASPX markup), this wouldn't be an issue. However, it's been my experience that the `DataSource` property is never automatically persisted when it has been set dynamically (in the code-behind).

The solution is to either re-run the `Select` query and re-set the datasource prior to rebinding, or to manually persist the datasource and then you can rebind at will.

To manually persist the datasource, I typically go with a protected page property that I store in ViewState.

```
protected SqlDataReader GridView1DataSource {
    get {
        SqlDataReader reader = null;

        if (ViewState("SomeStringUniqueToThePageThatICanUseAsAKeyAndRemainsDescriptive") != null) {
            reader = ViewState("SomeStringUniqueToThePageThatICanUseAsAKeyAndRemainsDescriptive");
        }

        return reader;
    }
    set { ViewState("SomeStringUniqueToThePageThatICanUseAsAKeyAndRemainsDescriptive") = value; }
}
```

Then

1. set the page property

   `this.GridView1DataSource = reader;`
2. set the datasource to the page property

   `GridView1.DataSource = this.GridView1DataSource;`
3. rebind whenever you need to

   `GridView1.DataBind();`

There is no reason you cannot use both of these techniques, but if you need the datasource to actually update, you'll need to re-run the query before re-persisting it in the page property.

The other side of this is that if you don't need the datasource to actually update, you might not even need to rebind the `GridView` datasource in the `DDL4_SelectedIndexChanged` postback handler.

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
    runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="id,status"                       
    AllowSorting="True" 
    HorizontalAlign="Center" 
    Font-Names="Arial" 
    Font-Size="Medium" 
    CellPadding="3" 
    BackColor="Gray" 
    BorderColor="#0A2C2A" 
    BorderStyle="Ridge" 
    BorderWidth="2px" 
    CellSpacing="1"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    EnableViewState = "true" 
    >

Comment: I see the rebind issue now. Copy/Paste fail. :(  The rest of what you said seems logical, but is about 4oz. more than I can hold in my head at a time. It will take me sometime to process. In the mean time I replaced the rebind with DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);  It's a bit of a kludge, but it accomplishes the re-query and gives me an instant re-view on each action taken which is exactly the behavior I was looking for.  Thank You!